# could not deploy due to insufficient funds

Tags: ethereum

"Issue: I encountered the following error today, even though I had no issues when testing the transaction ten days ago. I have 1.4 ETH in my MetaMask wallet, so there shouldn't be a gas shortage. How can I resolve this?

Error Message:

markdown
Copy code
"DrivingLicense" could not deploy due to insufficient funds

- Account: 0x8455aB650b249a20721a9B047623977fB6b96946
- Balance: 974578277345868936 wei
- Message: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: balance 974578277345868936, tx cost 2957110447896000000, overshot 1982532170550131064
- Try:

  - Using an adequately funded account
  - If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced."
    Please help me with a solution. Thank you!"

truffle test --network sepolia
and gas fee

Comment: Could you share the contract you used and the scripts to deploy it?